# Line/text will not center

Tags: alignment, center

I have tried using `border-bottom` to add a line to `h1`, but then the `h1` won't center. Another attempt was `text-decoration: underline` but nothing changed. For the centering, I tried using it on the `table`, `tr`, `td`. I'm trying to have a 2px line go underneath the `h1`. What am I doing wrong?

```
hr.hrNews {
    background-color: #000000;
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    max-width: 236px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}

<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle;">
            <h1 style="text-align: center;">In The News</h1>
            <hr class="hrNews" />
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

[image: UPDATE: This is what I see on Dreamweaver and Wordpress]

Comment: I'm not sure what you are seeing. http://jsbin.com/mujekuloma/edit?html,css,output This looks like what you want. If the height of the `hr` is the issue, change it's style to `border: 2px solid #000000` like I did in the JSBIN link.

Comment: I have two main columns with a lot of code and the style works, but it won't center. Same thing is happening when I try it in Wordpress.

Comment: Make a js fiddle to replicate. I'll take a look.

Comment: I just copied the code for this section and it looks fine, but not centered on the screen. https://jsfiddle.net/tantalizea/hy9Lh49o/1/ I uploaded an image that shows the text centered and line on the left. That's what I see on Dreamweaver and Wordpress. I know it's something with the code I don't have right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the `text-align` property on the `<h1>`'s container: http://jsbin.com/jujurobebo/edit?html,css,output

```
#bottom{
  min-width: 500px;
}
#top{
  text-align: center;
}
h1{
  width: 230px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block; 
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
#bottom img{
  width: 250px
}
#bottom p{
  width: 250px; 
  margin: 0; 
}
#bottom img, 
#bottom #left{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: +1 for good solution - examine the code and compare to what you posted at jsfiddle - no offence but yours is all over the shop floor - you have empty <td> and your </table> tag before you close one of your </div>'s (ie: tags closing out of sequence) and that's just for starters. Also note that if I'm not mistaken, any text-align is now preferred in CSS meaning that the use of it is deprecated in HTML5 standard. Failure to do this can result in your files not passing W3C markup validation and can also impact your rankings in Google for example. JMO to but ditch Dreamweaver pronto = learn code

Comment: Apologies for the comment here - probably should have posted in OP's comments section but it's 2AM here and light out time :)

Comment: Sorry, tokenloko--I just copied and pasted pieces, so I wasn't paying attention. Since I was using tables, I tried to apply it to `<td>`, `<tr>`, etc as the parent container, where nothing worked. Someone pointed out that it shouldn't be in `style="___"`, since `align="center"` could be used. Thanks for the help, everyone! I'll try to post more precise code when asking for help next time :)